# Use the same code for different domain in a different folder

Tags: php, apache, directory, vps

I have 4 domains that use the same code (PHP code). I have third party PHP apps (phpmailer, XML parser etc...) and my own (custom PDO class, custom libraries, etc...).

```
domain1 => /usr/local/httpd/domain1.com/
domain2 => /usr/local/httpd/domain2.com/
domain3 => /usr/local/httpd/domain3.com/
domain4 => /usr/local/httpd/domain4.com/
```

I don't want to copy 4 times the same code is there an easy way to use the same code for all these 4 folders?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place the code all of your domains share in /usr/local/httpd/shared/ and modify the scripts in domain1-4 to load that stuff from the shared directory. (This actually makes a whole lot of sense, especially when you're running something like [APC](http://php.net/apc)).

Answer (score -2):

```
domain1 => /usr/local/httpd/domain1.com/
domain2 => /usr/local/httpd/domain1.com/
domain3 => /usr/local/httpd/domain1.com/
domain4 => /usr/local/httpd/domain1.com/
```

in the code

```
$actual_domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

Comment: I have 4 different domain which they have their own folders I don't want to mix them with the other one.